# class java.lang.RuntimeException in glassfish when i try to create new JDBC Resources

Tags: glassfish

class java.lang.RuntimeException in glassfish when i try to create new JDBC Resources.

This is the exception. Following is the snapshot:

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Can you provide more information?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Here are some help pages to get you started: [Asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) If you can update your question, someone will be able to help you.

Comment: What are you exactly asking.?

Comment: when i try to deploy my Enterprise application this message appear : E:\LESSONS\Projects\NetBeansProjects\EJB\lec4\LogInApp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:307: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details. and the server gave me this exception Severe:   Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : java:module/TestDB__pm
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : java:module/TestDB__pm . and now i try to create new JDBC resources

Comment: and i got this Exception : class java.lang.RuntimeException

Answer (score 5):

I've been having same issues with the latest Glassfish 4.1. I couldn't find any solution on how to resolve RuntimeException when using web interface to add new resources. From what I understand it is a major bug that hasn't been resolved yet ([GLASSFISH-21437](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21437)). Meanwhile, I manually add JDBC Connection Pool and JDBC Resource entries by modifying domain.xml file located in the domain's config folder:

```
    glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml
```

Just make sure that you make a backup copy just in case you make a mistake. You will need to restart Glassfish.

You can also use asadmin CLI commands to add resources. I have not done this myself but instructions on how to do that can be found in [Glassfish administration guide (chapter 5)](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/administration-guide.pdf).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just uninstall the version you are running  and install a stable version [here](http://download.java.net/glassfish/4.1/release/glassfish-4.1.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found the only solution to replace glassfish 4.1.1 with version 4.1.0. This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that BUG is fixed (https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21314). I created JDBC resurce without exception

Answer (score 0):

Update to 4.1.2 .

I had the same issue with Glassfish 4.1.1 , until now I set up all with asadmin commands , but the bug has been fixed with version 4.1.2 , no more exception thrown while creating new JDBC ressources .

Answer (score 0):

I have to download another version of glassfish, in my case "GlassFish 5.0 - Web Profile" https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download , after in netbeans i removed the old GlassFish setting up the new version and everything was fine.